# How to list deleted remote branches of git using shell commands

Tags: git

I want to know how can we get the list of the names git remote branches which were deleted with in 30 days on Linux machine.

Is this something possible? I have tried many things and searched many things on google but no luck.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

To list all [remote-tracking branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) (`git branch --remote`) that are no longer available on the remote (sadly without any time frame):

```
git fetch --prune --dry-run
```

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> -p
>   --prune
>       Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the      remote.
>
> --dry-run
>       Show what would be done, without making any changes.